# Combining scatter and customBars in Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs, scatter, errorbar

I'm trying to build a dygraphs with 2 series one type: scatter another type: errorBars but it seems like it can only display either one:

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="dygraph.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:1000px; height:600px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

new Dygraph(
document.getElementById("container"),
    [
        [new Date("2016/2/3"), [1,3,6], [4]],
        [new Date("2016/3/3"), [1,3,6], [3]],
        [new Date("2016/4/3"), [1,3,6], [1]],
        [new Date("2016/5/3"), [1,3,6], [2]],
        [new Date("2016/6/3"), [1,3,6], [6]],
        [new Date("2016/7/3"), [1,3,6], [5]]
    ],
{
    labels: [ "Date", "SD" , "Scatter"],
    showRangeSelector: true,
    customBars: true,
    drawPoints: true,
    series: {
        "SD" : {

        },
        "Scatter" : {
            customBars: false,
            strokeWidth: 0.0
        }
    },
    includeZero: true

}
);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If customBars are commented off,it shows the scatter plot.
If not it shows custom bars. Never both. 
Here is the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCPs.png)

here is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nswczp2o/1/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!! 
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Justine, I can not run your JSfiddle as the references to the dygraphs libraries are not set. Which version are you using? Could you fix the JSfiddle to be able to run your example. Regards

Comment: Ok, I have added the external sources https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.css and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.js and it is working now. I will try to find a solution ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m not sure if it is possible to mix custombar graphs with non custom bars ones. But I have found the next solution to your problem. Why don´t you create the graph you want without custombar as a custombar with no custom bar area. Below I leave you my solution.

I hope this could be a solution for you ;)

```js
new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("container"),
 [
     [new Date("2016/2/3"), [1,3,6], [4,4,4]],
     [new Date("2016/3/3"), [1,3,6], [3,3,3]],
     [new Date("2016/4/3"), [1,3,6], [1,1,1]],
     [new Date("2016/5/3"), [1,3,6], [2,2,2]],
     [new Date("2016/6/3"), [1,3,6], [6,6,6]],
     [new Date("2016/7/3"), [1,3,6], [5,5,5]]
 ],
 {
       labels: [ "Date", "SD" , "Scatter"],
       showRangeSelector: true,
       customBars: true,
       drawPoints: true,
          
   series: {
    "SD" : {
     
    },
    "Scatter" : {
     strokeWidth: 1
    }
   },
   includeZero: true
   
  }
 );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.0.0/dygraph.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:1000px; height:600px;"></div>
```

Comment: You're correct that `customBars` (i.e. data format) cannot be set per-series. Your workaround is the best option. See https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/319

Comment: You´re welcome @Justine. If you consider the answer as correct, would you be so kind of voting it up and marking it as correct? Thanks!

Comment: @LucidioVacas done! but I'm too new so my vote doesn't increase the post score :P